# Update some field values after user update own account

Tags: 8, users

On my Drupal 8 project, usernames are only allowed to be emails. For that, on account creation, I am setting the *name* field equal to the *email* field, and users don't have the permission to edit their own usernames.

I am writing the code to update the username when the users change email. This is the code I wrote so far.

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_user_update().
 * Set Username = mail if mail has been updated by user.
 */
function hook_user_update($account) {
  $current_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
  $original_email = $account->original->get('mail')->value;
  $updated_email = $current_user->get('mail')->value;

  if ($original_email != $updated_email) {
    $current_user->setUsername($updated_email);
    $current_user->save();
  }

}
```

Since the code is saving a user object, the same hook is invoked again when `$current_user` is saved. I also tried with `hook_user_save()` and `hook_user_presave()`, but they don't work until I include `$current_user->save();` in the code.

**Update:**

Using `hook_user_presave()`

```
function custom_module_user_presave($account) {
  $current_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
  $original_email = $account->original->get('mail')->value;
  $updated_email = $current_user->get('mail')->value;

  if ($original_email != $updated_email) {
    $current_user->setUsername($updated_email);
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t("if"));
  }
  else {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t("else"));
  }
```

However, after updating the email and saving an existing user, I always get the message: **else** which means `$original_email != $updated_email` which is logic as the user has not been not saved yet.

any help please ?

Comment: I believe you want `hook_user_presave()`: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.8.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal core doesn't use any [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.9.x/search/hook_ENTITY_TYPE) hook and [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.9.x) is called after saving in the database an entity that has been updated.
As the documentation says, that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data. They shouldn't call `save()` on the entity they receive as argument, or that will invoke those hook implementations once again; if then those hook implementations don't check if they have been already invoked (which is the case of most, if not all, the hook implementations) and save again the entity they received as argument, that would cause an infinite loop.

The only hook invoked before the entity is saved is [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.9.x), which is invoked either when an entity is created or updated. It's easy to understand in which case the hook is invoked, since in the latter case `$entity->original` will contain the entity before the change.

As side note, the documentation reference to that hook as `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`; the implementation done from the *mymodule* module for the User entity is `mymodule_user_presave()`. (Replace *ENTITY_TYPE* with the entity type for which the hook should be invoked, such as *user* for the User entity and *node* for the Node entity.)

As for the used code, that is wrong since:

- There isn't the need to load the account with `\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id())` because the full User object is already passed to the hook as argument
- Since the hook is invoked whenever a new user is created, or an existing user is updated, the code needs to first verify `$account->original` is defined
- The code is setting the username for `$current_user`, but Drupal core is saving `$account`; since in PHP those are two different objects, the code isn't changing the username for the User object being saved
- `$original_email != $updated_email` is not comparing the changed email with the original email, but it's comparing the email before the User object is edited with the original email (which is still the email before the User object is edited)

I would use the following code.

```
function custom_module_user_presave($account) {
  if (isset($account->original)) {
    $original_email = $account->original->get('mail')->value;
    $updated_email = $account->get('mail')->value;

    if ($original_email != $updated_email) {
      $account->setUsername($updated_email);
    }
  }
}
```

Even better, the code should check the value returned from `$account->isNew()`.

```
function custom_module_user_presave($account) {
  if (!$account->isNew()) {
    $original_email = $account->original->get('mail')->value;
    $updated_email = $account->get('mail')->value;

    if ($original_email != $updated_email) {
      $account->setUsername($updated_email);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as i have mentioned in my question, I have aleady tried with `hook_user_presave()` but for some reason isn't working... Can you check please the update to my question

Comment: You need to verify `$account->original` is defined. Then, `\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage()` is not the correct way to debug a hook.

Comment: Also, there is no need to load the account, as that is already passed to the hook.

Comment: I found this issue here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2839195 but not sure if related to my issues on why `$account->original` is not defined ! What do you think ? is it a core issue ?

Comment: No, that issue is about an implementation detail. The only case `$account->original` is not set is when the the user is created. Since `hook_user_presave()` is invoked either when a user is created or when a user is updated, you need to check in which case the hook is invoked.

Comment: In my case the hook is invoked when user is updated, the user already has an account but yet  `$account->original` is not defined